# Representing sets in Mathematica

Tags: syntax

What is the right ways to define a mathematical set in Mathematica?

I wrote the line

```
A = {1, 2, 3}
```

and

```
A := {1, 2, 3}
```

Both cases work, but I don't know which if any is right.

Comment: `{}` is a `List` and the difference in `:` you can find in [difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/5478)

Comment: There is no *set* data structure in Mathematica, only lists. There are functions such as `Union` which treat lists as if they were sets (they sort the lists and remove duplicate elements).  You should check [this page](https://www.wolfram.com/language/), choose a tutorial you find suitable for your level of knowledge, and work through at least the first few chapters.

Comment: https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/ or https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/ or https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/

Answer (score 2):

a = {1, 2, 3} is the correct way.

Comment: does not work for me, if I input `a = {1,1}` it contains  duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 we got the cool new streams framework. In fact, one of the original designers of Java recommends to always use streams for all arrays / collections, unless you have specific reasons not to. Streams are the new default, especially together with collections.

```
Needs["JLink`"] 

ReinstallJava[]

LoadJavaClass["java.util.Arrays","StaticsVisible"->True];
LoadJavaClass["java.util.stream.Collectors","StaticsVisible"->True];

t[s_]:=Arrays`asList[MakeJavaObject/@s];

list={1,1,2,3,4,5};
set=Arrays`stream[MakeJavaObject/@list]@collect[Collectors`toSet[]];
set@toArray[]

set@addAll[t@Range@20];
set@toArray[]

set@addAll[t@Array[4&,20]];
set@toArray[]

set@removeAll[t@Range[3,20,3]];
set@toArray[]
```

Look at all you have in that object:

```
set//Methods
```

You can even process streams in parallel (look, there are stream and parallelStream methods), so now you can use all your cores for stream processing -- 8, 12, 16, 24, 36 ... however many cores you may have.